# How to tell, from within a running script, what Python interpreter is running it?

Tags: python, pyenv

I would like to output, in my script, the full path of the Python interpreter running it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("{}".format(full_path_of_interpreter_running_this_script)
```

The script is in the `PATH` and run as:

```
script.py
```

Can I do that? How?

Note: Doing `which python` or `type python` in `bash` does not help me, because I am using `pyenv`, and `pyenv` is doing shims magic.

Note: More than identifying the Python executable, I am interested in identifying the virtualenv that is being used, and I thought knowing the full path to the interpreter will help me in this.

Comment: try `sys.executable`

Comment: Thanks, great, this is exactly what I was looking for. An answer gets an upvote and an approve!

Comment: I had checked that there were no duplicate before answering, found none. Ok, answer added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gives the full path to the command that was used to run the script:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```